# Photos: Search all photos captured by a particular device (iPhone 5s)

Tags: photos.app, search

Is there any way in the new Photos app to search for all images taken from a particular device? I want to export all my iPhone images out of Photos app.

Currently my library has images imported from various other devices also.

Answer (score 4):

*I am not used to the Photos App, so this might not be the best solution but could solve your question.*

1. In the menubar go to `File` and then click on `New Smart Album...`
2. Select `Camera Model` from the first drop-down menu and then pick the rest to fit your needs.

[image: Screenshot]

To find out what exactly you need to type there, you can just get the info of a picture where you know that you took it with that device and see what exactly it says.

Edit: As it turns out, my old iPhone 5s says "Apple iPhone 5s" but this Smart Album only worked if I wrote `contains` "iPhone 5s", so that should work.